# How create SQL Server stored procedure, keeping line breaks and tabs, from record stored in database with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server: I have copied and saved a stored procedure in a database. During that process, it has escaped the line feeds and tabs into \n and \t characters throughout the stored procedure text so it looks like:

```
SQL = "create PROCEDURE ScrambleNames\n\t@removeAdmins bit \nAS\nBEGIN\n\t-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent..."  just shortened for clarity

using (DbConnection dbcn = dbf.CreateConnection())
{
    dbcn.ConnectionString = cnxn;
    dbcn.Open();

    using (DbCommand dbcmd = dbcn.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dbcmd.CommandText = SQL;

        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I want to read that SQL statement with C# and use it to create an actual stored procedure in another database by executing that command. Obviously, when I try and execute it without any changes, it says there is a syntax error near \ and fails. I've tried replacing the \n and \t with actual binary characters in the string but it fails with more errors:

> Incorrect syntax near '1'... etc.

So, how can I read the text from the database and keep the line feeds and tabs in the stored procedure I'm trying to create?

Comment: If it's complaining about a '\' character, it sounds like your string is double-escaped. Can you confirm that the C# string is `\n\t` and not `\\n\\t`?

Comment: my answer has been updated.

Comment: answer updated for more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **verbatim strings** with **@** to support multiline strings, like this

```
     SQL = @"create PROCEDURE ScrambleNames 
             @removeAdmins bit  
             AS BEGIN 
             -- comment here
             SELECT * FROM";

            using (DbConnection dbcn = dbf.CreateConnection())
            {
                dbcn.ConnectionString = cnxn;
                dbcn.Open();
                using (DbCommand dbcmd = dbcn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    dbcmd.CommandText = SQL;
                    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Example to explain verbatim string:

```
normal_string = "Line1 \n Line2 \n line3";
same_as_verbatim_string = @"Line1
                            Line2
                            line3";
```

Comment: I could remove those but the resulting stored procedure wouldn't be readable so I'd like to keep them in the resulting stored procedure.

Comment: @Velocedge I have updated my answer to support multi lines

Comment: VERY interesting... but not sure where to put the @.  The "string" is coming out of a database so should I use that when writing the original text into the database or can I read the database with \n's and \t's in it?

Comment: you put it once like this var ```sqlString = @"create stored procedure ......."``` and write it normally. See my last update has a straightforward example

Comment: dont use  \n's and \t'

Comment: @Velocedge  , added an example to my answer, both strings are equal.

Comment: I get that.  My bad... there is no SQL = "create stored procedure..."  my example is not correct.  It's really coming from the database so it's actually SQL = rs.GetValue(0).ToString().